# registration form checking order in php?

Tags: php, html, regex

i have a problem with this registration form, im checking the password and username, this is the process im doing it in?

php:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));


    //check if username is valid
        if (ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$", $username)){

             die(msg(0,"oOps, This username is not valid, only numbers, letters and underscores allowed"));

        }

        // check if password is more than 6

    if(strlen($password) < 6){

       die(msg(0,"oOps, The password has to be more than 6 characters, be tricky!"));
    }
```

but i type the user, password correctly, but its still giving me the errors shown, is thier something wrong with the checking :)) thanks

Comment: The hash length is the same no matter how long the password is. Also, you should be using a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_salt).

Comment: You also SHOULD NOT use `ereg` those functions are deprecated. Use `preg` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to check the validity of $username after passing it through mysql_real_escape_string() since that function will escape certain characters, and the resultant 'username' will end up containing '\' characters, and therefore always fail your regexp.

(Also, you appear to be checking for a username, and die()ing if it's *valid*. Are you sure that code is exactly how you're written it?)

Likewise, it doesn't make any sense to check the length of $password after passing it through md5(). md5() will convert anything into a 32-character string, so that condition will always fail.

P.S.

> // check if password is more than 6
>
> if(strlen($password) < 6){

If you're going to over-comment code, at least make sure the comment is accurate! ;-)

Comment: so basically i should check before taking them through mysql escape and md5!!

Comment: for the username checking i just want to allow _ 0-9 a-z only, how would i change it

Comment: P.S. Note that 'if (ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$", $username)) { die(); }' effectively means "if the username only contains basic characters, die because it's invalid" - I *don't* think that's what you intended

Comment: just reverse the logic: if (ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$", $username) === FALSE) { die(); }

Comment: can you change for me please, im so stupid at this stuff @bobby, thanks

Comment: N.B. I've removed the escaping backslash from that character class on purpose - from memory, you don't need to escape hyphen (-) if it's the last character in the square brackets, since it's unambiguous

Comment: thanks @bobby the username checking is not working, i just typed ..... in the username box and its letting me?

Comment: Hmmm... is it possible for you to supply the entire code? (if it's too long, you can use something like pastebin)